# 3D Image visualisation with nilearn

Tags: python, 3d, nifti, mri, nilearn

I used plot_glass_brain to visualize 3D image (Nifti) with nilearn but it is displayed incorrectly. see code and pictures below

The `2_1_t2.nii` file is available on this link : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_gsg8sO9c7Ws6Xd7xB1uFSW8H31tAHtm/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from nilearn.plotting import plot_anat, show
plotting.plot_glass_brain('2_1_t2.nii')
plotting.show()
```

Comment: can you please provide the `2_1_t2.nii` file along with the code so it turns to be a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I added a link to the file `2_1_t2.nii`  to my original post above

Comment: maybe you have to map fMRI voxels to MNI (Montreal imaging institute) coordinate space.

Comment: Indeed - from the `srow_x` etc. values you can see that your image is not aligned to the MNI space, which the glass brain is. You can do this alignment in Python using `dipy`.